# Why bash echo string length is 28

Tags: c, linux, bash, kernel

I am writing my own procfs read write handler.

```
static ssize_t mywrite(struct file *file, const char __user *ubuf, size_t count, loff_t *ppos) 
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "write handler\n");
    int num,c,i,m;
    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    if(*ppos > 0 || count > BUFSIZE){
        printk(KERN_ALERT "failed *ppos > 0 || count > BUFSIZE");
        return -EFAULT;
    }
    if(copy_from_user(buf, ubuf, count)){
        printk(KERN_ALERT "FAILED copy_from_user(buf, ubuf, count)");
        return -EFAULT;
    }

    int characters_in_input = strlen(buf);
    printk(KERN_INFO "wrote %s in file and it's length is %d \n",buf,characters_in_input);
    return characters_in_input;
}
 
static ssize_t myread(struct file *file, char __user *ubuf,size_t count, loff_t *ppos) 
{
    some logic
}
    static struct file_operations myops = 
    {
        .owner = THIS_MODULE,
        .read = myread,
        .write = mywrite,
    };
 
static int simple_init(void)
{
    ent=proc_create("mydev",0777,NULL,&myops);
    printk(KERN_ALERT "hello...\n");
    return 0;}
```

And when I write smth from c code like

```
int fd = open("/proc/mydev", O_RDWR);
lseek(fd, 0 , SEEK_SET);
if(write(fd, "1", 10)==-1){
    printf("write failed");
};
```

handler output is "wrote 1 in file and it's length is 1 "
but if I use bash and execute

```
echo "asd" > /proc/mydev
```

handler output is  "wrote asd

\xa8B\x99ٚ\xff\xff\xa6\xb9\xff\xff\xff\xff辠Z\xb2\xff\xff in file and it's length is 28 "

Comment: Looks like C strings are null terminated, but bash strings are not.  After the copy_from_user, try buf[count] = 0.

Comment: @cup bash strings are probably null-terminated. But it doesn't write the null.

Comment: @cup Re "*Looks like C strings are null terminated, but bash strings are not.*", How bash strings look is not relevant. bash is written in C, isn't it? So they would be NUL-terminated. This isn't about bash's strings. This is about what gets written out. And just like `printf("%s", "abc\n")` doesn't output the NUL that is there, neither does bash's `echo`

Answer (score 2):

Re your code:

```
int characters_in_input = strlen(buf);
```

There's nothing *requiring* a caller to terminate their data with a `\0`, which is what would be needed for `strlen` to work properly:

- Your C code uses `"1"` which is stored in memory as the characters `1` and `\0`, and a length of 10. Hence the `\0` will be there.
- However, the `echo` command will send four characters: `a`, `s`, `d`, and `\n` with a length of four. It will *not* send a `\0`.

You can confirm the `echo` behaviour with something like:

```sh
/home/pax> echo asd | xxd
00000000: 6173 640a
```

It's also evident by what your program logged (from your question):

```
wrote asd
\xa8B\x99ٚ\xff\xff\xa6\xb9\xff\xff\xff\xff辠Z\xb2\xff\xff in file and it's length is 28
```

That has the `asd` and the `\n` newline, followed by a lot lot of arbitrary bytes that are beyond what you provided, because both `printf("%s")` and `strlen()` expect a properly terminated C string.

---

In fact, the whole *point* of the `count` parameter is so that you can operate with binary data rather than strings. It allows you to send data with embedded `\0` characters and have them treated correctly.

So I would be using *that* rather than trying to work out how long the data is.